# HtmlAgility Xpath "div" not working

Tags: xpath, html-agility-pack

HTML:

```
<div style="margin-left: 24pt; text-indent: -24pt" aaBT="xx" xx="a)">
      <p class="norm">a)<span style="word-spacing: 15pt"> </span>„xxx</p>
      <p class="list">asdf</p>
   <div aaBT="xx">blub<p class="list">blabla</p></div></div>
```

Testing in console

```
?T.ChildNodes.ToArray
{Length=6}
    (0): Name: "#text"
    (1): Name: "p"
    (2): Name: "#text"
    (3): Name: "p"
    (4): Name: "#text"
    (5): Name: "div"
?T.SelectSingleNode("div")
Nothing
```

How could it be, that "div" is not found, while "div" is a child node?

Comment: Where's the xpath in your question?

Comment: Xpath is just "div".
T.SelectSingleNode("div")

Comment: Try  T.SelectSingleNode("./div")  to select relatively to the current element T